# Variadic templates and argument overloading don't work together

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, overloading

I'm trying to write a simple variadic function, which will be able to support many different types, but what have I done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void parse(void) {}


template<typename... Rest>
void parse(bool* pValue, Rest... restArgs) {
    cout << "bool*\n";
    parse(restArgs...);
}

template<typename... Rest>
void parse(int* pValue, Rest... restArgs) {
    cout << "int*\n";
    parse(restArgs...);
}

int main() {
    bool a1;
    int a2;
    parse(
        &a1,
        &a2);
}
```

When arguments in parse is int*, bool* - program works. But when I change order, a compiler (g++ 4.8.4) complains:

```
variadic.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void parse(bool*, Rest ...) [with Rest = {int*}]’:
variadic.cpp:25:6:   required from here
variadic.cpp:11:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘parse(int*&)’
  parse(restArgs...);
                   ^
variadic.cpp:11:19: note: candidates are:
variadic.cpp:5:6: note: void parse()
 void parse(void) {}
      ^
variadic.cpp:5:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
variadic.cpp:9:6: note: template<class ... Rest> void parse(bool*, Rest ...)
 void parse(bool* pValue, Rest... restArgs) {
      ^
variadic.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variadic.cpp:11:19: note:   cannot convert ‘restArgs#0’ (type ‘int*’) to type ‘bool*’
  parse(restArgs...);
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to forward declare the other overload:

```
template<typename... Rest>
void parse(int* pValue, Rest... restArgs);

template<typename... Rest>
void parse(bool* pValue, Rest... restArgs) {
  std::cout << "bool*" << std::endl;
  parse(restArgs...);
}

template<typename... Rest>
void parse(int* pValue, Rest... restArgs) {
  std::cout << "int*" << std::endl;
  parse(restArgs...);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dad85063c280a0d5)

Comment: Big thank, it make sense ... Mistake in my example was, that compiler tried to expand template at first function - before it know that another overload better fit its requirements. Great!